# How to read the xml sent to my webservice

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I want to read the XML from my client'application (WindowsForm vb.net) to my webservice.  
I send an image, so i convert it in a byte(). But i also thought about send it in Base64String.  
I want to check which is the more efficient.  
By the way, when i execute the webservice in Visual Studio, i saw there are XML. But my probleme is : i can't insert datas in my byteArray so i can't check...  
(PS: sorry for my english)

Comment: Please show some code. Also, is this a WCF web service, or a legacy ASMX service? In both cases, you usually don't need to process XML, so your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Stumpy, i'm gonna try this.

I also find another way with this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check which is the more efficient.

You can watch the http frames with a tool like fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) and compare the size of each one. Easy to select the best solution after that :).